# Partially ordered set and a method that can quickly solve these questions?!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

> I prepare for Msc Qualification exam. This is 2015 Exams, with Answer
>   is option (2).

Set $M={2,3,4,...}$ is given. Suppose $M \times M$ is sorted in which $ (a,b) \leq (c,d)$ if and only if $c$ is Divisible on $a$ and condition $b \leq d$ is  hold. Which of these option is true about minimal and maximal elemetns of partial ordered set $(M \times M, \leq)$? in following option $p$ is arbitrary prime number.

1) each pair $(p,m)$ for $m \in M$ be a minimal element and there is no maximal element.

2) each pair $(p,m)$ for $m \in M$ be a minimal element and there is maximal element.

3) each pair $(p,2)$ for $m \in M$ be a minimal element and there is no maximal element.

4) each pair $(p,m)$ for $m \in M$ be a minimal element and there is maximal element.

---

*my challenge is via a method that can solve this problem and like it, in a quick way? is it any description or hint?*

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that option (3) is correct.

- $\boxed{(p, m) \text{ is not minimal for }m \geq 3}$: Since $m \geq 3$, we know that $m - 1 \geq 2$, so $(p, m - 1) \in M \times M - \{(p, m)\}$. Since $p \mid p$ and $m - 1 \leq m$, we have that $(p, m - 1) \leq (p, m)$.
- $\boxed{\text{There is no maximal element}}$: Given any candidate maximal element $(p, q) \in M \times M$, notice that $p \mid p$ and $q \leq q + 1$ so that $(p, q) \leq (p, q + 1)$. Thus, since $(p, q + 1) \in M \times M - \{(p, q)\}$, we have found a different element larger than the candidate maximal element.

Comment: I didnt get the point for section that "not minimal?

Comment: It establishes that options (1), (2), and (4) are all wrong.

Comment: Would you please take me an example for part one of your answer? thanks

Comment: Hi, I study more, would you please a bit more describe it?

Comment: Try some examples. Why is $(7, 4)$ not minimal? Because $(7, 2) \leq (7, 3) \leq (7, 4)$. Indeed, start with any ordered pair and try to find one that's smaller until you can't. For example:
$$
(30, 5) \geq (15, 5) \geq (15, 4) \geq (15, 3) \geq (3, 3) \geq (3, 2)
$$
Noticed that we had to stop once the first number was prime and the second number was two.

Comment: this example not hold the question condition :) I couldn't success in verify an example for the condition in this question. would you please help me

Comment: sorry, I need to describe an example for me to approve, thanks